# Exact vs. approximated form of dipole susceptibility for stimulated emission in laser

Tags: polynomials, physics

Stimulated emission in laser can be described by the classical oscillator theory (A.E. Siegman *Lasers* chapter 2 University Science Books 1986).

According to Siegman, the overall susceptibility is
$$\tilde{\chi}={Ne^2\over m\epsilon}{1\over \omega_a^2-\omega^2+j\omega\Delta\omega_a}$$

The exact form of the imaginary part:
$${\chi}_e={-Ne^2\over m\epsilon}{j\omega\Delta\omega_a\over (\omega_a^2-\omega^2)^2+\omega^2{\Delta\omega_a}^2}$$

When $\omega\approx \omega_a$, $\omega_a^2-\omega^2 \approx 2\omega_a(\omega_a-\omega)$, the exact form of the imaginary part can be approximated by:
$${\chi}_a={-Ne^2\over m\epsilon}{j\omega_a\Delta\omega_a\over 
 4\omega_a^2(\omega_a-\omega)^2+\omega_a^2{\Delta\omega_a}^2}$$

In exercise question 5 of section 2.4, the author asks how far $\omega$ can deviate from $\omega_a$, so that

$${\left\vert {\chi}_e - {\chi}_a\right\vert\over {\chi}_e}=0.1$$

If I do it in a straight forward way, I will get a fourth order polynomial of $\omega$, which doesn't seem possible to get the solution. What is the correct approach here?

For this question, both $\omega_a$ and $\Delta\omega_a$ are known quantities.

This is the original question. [Original question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kudMX.png)

Comment: Which of these things are real and which are complex?

Comment: only $j$ is imaginary, everything else is real and positive

Comment: Is "$m\epsilon$" supposed to be $\mu \epsilon$?

Comment: No, it is supposed to be $m\epsilon$, $m$ for electronic mass. This part will be cancelled out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, expanding in one-term Taylor series in $\omega$ centered at $\omega_a$, we have (cases are to make the absolute value pick a sign)
\begin{align*}
\omega &> \omega_a  &&: & \frac{|\chi_e - \chi_a|}{\chi_e} &\approx \frac{\omega - \omega_a}{\omega_a}  \\
\omega &< \omega_a  &&: & \frac{|\chi_e - \chi_a|}{\chi_e} &\approx -\frac{\omega - \omega_a}{\omega_a}
\end{align*}
From these, the range of $\omega$ is $-[0.9, 1.1]\omega_a$.  The minus sign is because $\chi_e$ in the denominator is negative.  It is far more common to write the relative error as either of
$$  \left| \frac{\chi_e - \chi_a}{\chi_e} \right| = \left| 1 - \frac{\chi_a}{\chi_e} \right|  $$
to correctly deal with negative and nonzero exact values.  See the brief discussion of "relative error" at [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error#Formal_definition].

Expanding to two terms,
\begin{align*}
\omega &> \omega_a  &&: & \frac{|\chi_e - \chi_a|}{\chi_e} &\approx -\frac{\omega - \omega_a}{\omega_a} + \frac{4 (\omega - \omega_a)^3}{\omega_a \Delta\omega_a^2} \\
\omega &< \omega_a  &&: & \frac{|\chi_e - \chi_a|}{\chi_e} &\approx \frac{\omega - \omega_a}{\omega_a} - \frac{4 (\omega - \omega_a)^3}{\omega_a \Delta\omega_a^2}
\end{align*}
We *could* solve this cubic, but determining which root is real requires knowing which of $\omega_a > \frac{10}{3 \sqrt{3}}\Delta\omega_a$, $\omega_a = \frac{10}{3 \sqrt{3}}\Delta\omega_a$, or $\omega_a \leq \frac{10}{3 \sqrt{3}}\Delta\omega_a$ holds.  You didn't indicate what is "big" and what is "small", so we don't have the information to resolve this.  If it happens that $\omega_a \gg \Delta \omega_a$, then the range is
$\omega \in [\omega_a -r, \omega_a + r]$ where
$$r = \frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{5}{3}}
   \Delta\omega
   _a^2}{2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{9
   \Delta\omega
   _a^2
   \omega _a+\sqrt{3} \sqrt{27
   \Delta\omega
   _a^4
   \omega _a^2-100
   \Delta\omega
   _a^6}}}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{9
   \Delta\omega
   _a^2
   \omega _a+\sqrt{3} \sqrt{27
   \Delta\omega
   _a^4
   \omega _a^2-100
   \Delta\omega
   _a^6}}}{2\
   3^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{10}} \text{.} $$
While that is certainly a thing which *can* be computed, I don't see that it provides much insight, so is probably not the desired answer.